# working on lamp server in ubuntu

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu-9.10

i m working on ubuntu and just installed lamp.As i m new to linux i m not sure how to create a directory or file under /var/www of lamp server to start working on my website project

Answer (score 2):

Under *nix you can create a directory using `mkdir newdirname` and you can create a new and empty file, using `touch newfilename`. Those are commands you need to execute from a shell/terminal. In order to get to `/var/www`, you will need to `cd /var/www`.

If you are new to Linux I suggest reading any guide on basic like [this](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/commands.htm) or [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/gs/gs.html).

Comment: thank you so much the way u explained was awesome...n i ll read these tutorials now...:-)

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you do not have sufficient privileges as your normal user to add files or create directories.  You can either change the ownership of the /var/www directory (and everything within) or you can `sudo` each one you want to add.

From the prompt:  chown [your_user_name].users -R /var/www

Then you can `mkdir [directory name]` to make a directory or `touch [filename]` to create a file.

If you do not change the permissions of the /var/www you may need to put `sudo` in front of each of the above commands (will be prompted for password)

Comment: ya i have the access to the root ....but thnks for the syntax of creating a directory that wat i was looking for....thnkwieeeeeee